# Xtensor: Help needed while assigning to a view

Tags: numpy, indexing, c++14, xtensor

The output after assigning to a view was broadcasted with a single element although shapes of the source and destination views are the same. Please let me know where exactly am I doing the mistake.

Please refer to the code and output image attached.

[NB output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOl4g.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the shapes are not the same: The dimensions don't match. `bb` has a dimension of 3.

So to make it work, one needs to either `squeeze`, in order to remove the first dimension, or use concatenate like this:

```
xt::xarray<float, xt::layout_type::row_major> bb = xt::eval(xt::concatenate(xt::xtuple(b1, b2, b3, b4), 1));
```